# Make image for back button fit the entire button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mobile, mobile-application

I'm developing an application where I use `UINavigationController`. I would like to set the image for a back button. I do this using the code below.

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backArrow.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

But the image appears only in the middle of the back button. How can I set the image to span the whole back button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For back button in `UINavigationBar`, if you add image it will show an image in center of the back buttobn only. You cannot add image in that too. So instead of doing that, hide your `backbutton` and add this code in your `viewDidload` Method to add a image for it and looks like what you need.

```
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_normal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_pressed"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button addTarget: nil action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);  
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: button];
```